# document.links outputs unknown elements

Tags: javascript

Something goes wrong when I try outputting the elements from `document.links` array. Is the cause coming from *wrong implementation of for-loop* ??. Have a look :

```
    // below is the HMTL 
    <p>
    <a name="one" href="http://www.kaskus.co.id">Kaskus</a><br>
    <a name="two" href="http://www.bola.net">Bola-net</a><br>
    <a name="three" href="http://www.kompas.co.id">Kompas</a><br>
    </p>        
     ....................
     ....................
     .....................

 // below is the JS 
 <script type="text/javascript">
     for( i in document.links){
          document.write("<br>"+document.links[i].text);
         }
 </script>
```

And the output is :

Kaskus
Bola-net
Kompas
`undefined`        <-- this is even funny,what is this ? 
 
Kaskus
Bola-net
Kompas
`undefined`
`undefined`

What probably causes  such *undefined*  ?

Comment: `document links` also includes all `<link>` elements in the head, `<area>` etc. and not just anchors.

Comment: no <link> in the head ..

Comment: You should be using `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`

Comment: And finally, `document.links` is an array-like collection, and should be iterated with a regular for loop, not `for-in`

Comment: Would you share the link after this one `<a name="three" href="http://www.kompas.co.id">Kompas</a>`.

Comment: Quick fiddle based on the above comments: http://jsfiddle.net/NGLvg/1/

Comment: @adeneo thx. and at gdahl elegant way of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.links` object gives you multiple ways to access the links in the document.

First, like an array, it has a numerical index for each one as well as a length (which is what you are complaining about with "this is even funny,what is this", numbers don't have a text property). Then, it lets you access them by name (so you get a second entry for each link). It also has a couple of functions dangling off it.

Change your code to:

```
document.write("<br>"+i+"  :  " +document.links[i].text);
```

And you'll see *all* the property names you are iterating through and it will make sense.

Don't use a `for in` loop, use a traditional array loop.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++){
     document.write("<br>"+document.links[i].text);
 }
```

You should have just `console.log(document.links)`, then you could have seen what all the properties you were dealing with were.

Comment: owwww.. you're right , ( length,item,namedItem ), now it makes sense , Thank you very much I get now !